# How to swap between two letters in a string char[]?

Tags: c

Sorry for the title, but I don't know what is this program called.

I'm trying to write a program that takes an `int` parameter and print a word of length `n` that consists of both letters 'a' and 'b'
for example:

```
n= 3 
the result =>: `aaa,baa,aba,aab,bba,bab,abb,bbb`
```

And this is my code. There is something wrong in it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n  5

char word[n] = "aaa";
char noob[n];

void
myfunction(void)
{
    int x,
     i,
     j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        // I did this to convert first from a char to int and then add one in
        // order to change a to b
        x = word[i];
        x++;
        word[i] = x;
        puts(word);

        // here is the problem after going through the first loob (i) we have
        // the word baa and it should go through the second loop j but it
        // doesn't
        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            noob[j] = word[j];
            word[j + 1] = word[j];
            word[j] = noob[j];
            puts(word);
        }

    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    myfunction();

    return 0;
}
```

can someone help me please ???

Comment: I would just go through numbers `[0..2^n-1]` and replace bits with letters..

Comment: Is it _only_ `a` and `b`? Or, could you also have a case where you would use (e.g.) `c`, `d`.

Comment: @CraigEstey  just 'a' and 'b'

Comment: @EugeneSh. what do you mean with 'replace bits with letters' or where ?

Comment: It does indeed go through your nested loop. Your logic is bad, though. You need to start up your debugger and walk through this code. By the time you get through your nested loop once, you'll know why this doesn't work. It may also give you an idea of how to re-write this code. Good luck.

Comment: @amerov For example for n=3, the numbers would be 0-7, which are represented in binary as `000`, `001`, `010`...`111`. The only thing you need is to decode these so for every `0` it will print `a`, and for every `1` it will print `b`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. for 000 it will print aaa and for 001 aab  right ?

Comment: @Amerov Whatever you define.. You might want to flip the order

Comment: Sorry I am missing something you defined in your code `n` as 5 and you are using as the length of your words to be generated but in your explanation you were talking about words of length 3? Exactly what output are you expecting when n is 5?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi if n=5 the output would be aaaaa baaaa abaaa.... bbbbb

Comment: Did you intend to print *all* possible combinations? Because that is not going to happen with those two loops! There are 2^n possible combinations, and you are printing at most n*(n-1) ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `char word[n] = "aaaaa";`

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define n  5

char word[n] = "aaaaa";
char noob[n];

void
myfunction(void)
{
    int x, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        // I did this to convert first from a char to int and then add one in
        // order to change a to b
        x = word[i];
        x++;
        word[i] = x;
        puts(word);

        // here is the problem after going through the first loob (i) we have
        // the word baa and it should go through the second loop j but it
        // doesn't
        for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
            noob[j] = word[j];
            word[j + 1] = word[j];
            word[j] = noob[j];
            puts(word);
        }

    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    myfunction();

    return 0;
}
```

Of course this work when you know the length of your words at compile time. It the length would be known only at runtime (for example with a user inputting it) you need do dynamically allocate (with `malloc` for example) and remove.